# where are the settings for the Release and Debug Build Configurations in .net core

Tags: .net-core

right now I have 3 build configurations: `Debug`, `Release` and `Cfg1`

I noticed that `Cfg1` would produce `dll` of the same size as `Debug` (larger than `Release`), so using trial and error I've found that adding this code in `project.json`:

```
  "configurations": {
    "Cfg1": { "buildOptions": { "optimize": true } }
  }
```

would make the dll the same size as `Release`

**however** , for both `Release` or `Debug` I couldn't find any configuration in `project.json` or in the solution file that would set `optimize: true`, so where is the configuration for `Debug` and `Release` is it embedded somewhere ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the configurations of `Debug` and `Release` are [hardcoded in .Net Core CLI code](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/v1.0.0-preview2.0.1/src/Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel/ProjectReader.cs#L353-L364).

In effect, the default configurations are:

```json
"configurations": {
  "Debug": {
    "buildOptions": {
      "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE"],
      "optimize": false
    }
  },
  "Release": {
    "buildOptions": {
      "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE"],
      "optimize": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't specified "define" for Cfg1, does that mean there is no "TRACE" and "Release", or is there a default value if "define" is not specified ?

Comment: @Omu There is no default, so no defines are specified in that case.